# how to use module in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

when I type "module available", it gives information of available of modules lie this.

```
--------------------------------- /tool/applic/module-3.2.10/Modules/3.2.10/modulefiles ----------------------------
Applic/Abaqus_2016_sp1       Applic/FDTD-8.15.716-1       Applic/Raphael_2006.12-SP2   Applic/Synopsys_sx_C2009-sp1
```

and I want to save this information every 1 min. by using **crontab**.

so I "crontab -e" and edit like this

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/1 * * * * module add something
*/1 * * * * module list >> croninfo.txt     
*/1 * * * * module available >> croninfo.txt
```

but **croninfo.txt** is empty.
It seems like "module" is not working.

how can I make module work so that I can add modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious possibilities here.

First, you have to keep in mind that `cron` runs its commands with an environment that is normally quite different from what you get in an interactive shell launched from a logged in session. You seem to have accounted for this by adding a `PATH` assignment, but it's important to remember. As an addenum to this, [cron runs the commands with the current working directory set to the owner user's home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160014/2465), so if that's not what you want you have to adjust accordingly.

Second, commands with the same time specifier are executed in an indeterminate order. When you write

```
*/1 * * * * module add something
*/1 * * * * module list >> croninfo.txt
*/1 * * * * module available >> croninfo.txt
```

you might think that they are going to be executed sequentially, one after the other, but in fact, *cron is free to execute them in whichever order it happens to like at the spur of the moment.* Depending on how long each command takes to start and execute, it's perfectly possible to have multiple different commands executing simultaneously.

If you want to execute a set of commands sequentially, **often the best approach is to make a simple script that runs the commands in the correct order, and only execute that script from within cron.**

Doing that will also allow you to use something like `#!/bin/bash -x` to get more details about the execution of the script, which can help pinpoint problems.

By the way, you don't need the `/1` specifier; `*` and `*/1` are equivalent on any sane cron implementation. The `/n` specifier is more useful when you want `n` to be something other than 1; for example, to execute a command every three minutes (`*/3` in the first time specifier field).

Comment: the problem is command "module" do not work by cron.

Comment: It should be something to do with the first issue that you commented 
how can I know what I have to append to my PATH to make module works.
In addition even "module" command works well, when I type "which module", it can't find where module source is. so I dont know which path I have to append to PATH

Comment: @최원우 I don't know what this `module` command is (it's certainly not one I am familiar with), but try `type module`.